# What is a MongoDB driver in layman's terms?

Tags: mongodb, driver

I've been scouring the MongoDB documentation, Google, Stackoverflow and YouTube... but I still can't seem to understand **what a driver is used for in MongoDB**.

I do know that different programming language can have one or many different drivers - but why do I need one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't strictly speaking *need* one, but the alternative is building network packets manually scattered around in your code base... The term 'driver' is a bit irritating, because most people expect some kernel-level program that talks to hardware.

The MongoDB driver is more like an SDK or a helper library that helps you with a number of tasks that you'll almost certainly need to solve when you want to use MongoDB.

In essence, the MongoDB driver does these things:

1. it implements the [MongoDB wire protocol](http://docs.mongodb.org/meta-driver/latest/legacy/mongodb-wire-protocol/) that is used to talk to the database, i.e. it knows what 'messages' the database expects, it knows relevant constants, etc. 'It implements the MongoDB API' if you will.
2. It also comes with helpers to manage the actual TCP/IP sockets, creating them, resolving replica set addresses, implementing connection pooling, etc.
3. Next, the drivers contain helpers that make it easier to work with the BSON datatypes from your language, since there normally isn't a 1:1 mapping of types. A mongodb array, for example, could be mapped to an array or some kind of list or set container in most languages; `ObjectId` and `ISODate` might need a wrapper, and so on.
4. Lastly, the driver implements a *serializer*, that is, a piece of software that can create a copy of an instance 'from the outside', that is, without you having to implement a `Serialize()` method on each and every `class` (or whatever concept your language supports) you want to store. Together with 3), this writes the BSON representation of your data.

Serialization in itself isn't trivial, because one quickly has to cope with cyclical references, so a recursive algorithm on a set of unknown properties is required. If that doesn't sound complicated enough, the de-serialization (or hydration) of objects is even more painful, so it's not exactly the type of code that is super rewarding to write, unless it's highly reusable.

I'm sure I forgot something else the drivers do, but I think these are the key pain points they solve. As far as I know, their exact feature set varies from language to language and in some languages, the individual problems might be less or more pronounced, but they generally exist everywhere.